# NumberLinePlot missing large segments of interval

Tags: plotting, version-10

What is going on here? Why isn't it extending to the full range?  Removing the `+ 0.0` gives the correct

```
NumberLinePlot[0 <= Sin[100*x + 0.0], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not start with the `bugs` tag applied even if something seems like an obvious bug.  It will be added later if it is confirmed as a bug by an authority or if the community agrees it is one.

Comment: It happens also with `Sin[100. *x]`, but not with `Sin[100*x + 0]`. Similarly, with `NumberLinePlot[0 <= Sin[10. *x], {x, 0, 10}]` or `NumberLinePlot[0 <= Sin[1. *x], {x, 0, 100}]` only a portion of the range is used.

Comment: I can't find any mention in the documentation of `NumberLinePlot` only working on exact input therefore this does seem like a bug to me, but we'll see what other people think.

Answer (score 4):

As the following demonstration shows, `NumberLinePlot` gives up at four intervals. On this showing I would call it a bug.

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    Plot[Sin[n x N[Pi]], {x, 0, 1}],
    NumberLinePlot[0 <= Sin[n x N[Pi]], {x, 0, 1}, Spacings -> 0, PlotStyle -> Red],
    ImageSize -> Large],
  {{n, 2}, 2, 12 , 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: demo]